# The two getter properties of the window object in the browsers

Tags: javascript, html, browser

I am reading the [Window interface reference in the HTML5 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/browsers.html#the-window-object). This reference (effectively) lists the properties of the `window` object in the browsers.

For instance, that interface contains these lines:

```
readonly attribute Document document;
```

which defines the `document` object and:

```
void alert(in DOMString message);
```

which defines the `alert` function.

However, there are two getter properties as well:

```
getter WindowProxy (in unsigned long index);
getter any (in DOMString name);
```

Now, I am not sure how these getter properties are used (in JavaScript). Like so: `window[1]`, `window[2]`, `window[3]` and `window['foo']`, `window['bar']`, `window['baz']`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The numerically-indexed values are "child browsing contexts", which I think will mostly be `<iframe>` elements. The string-indexed values are just the attributes of the object; global JavaScript variables, in other words.

And yes, your surmise as to how they're used is correct:

```
var children = window.length;
var frame2 = window[2];

var somevar = 17;
if (window['somevar'] === 17) alert('yup');
```

Comment: So, if I have a simple page with an IFRAME, then `window[0]` will refer to the window object of that IFRAME?

Comment: I tested it myself - it is. This means that `window` is a pseudo-array - it has indexed properties and a `length`.